# JFileChooser not showing up

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jfilechooser

I have a method that takes a `txt` file as an input. I used to use string by typing the direct path to the file. 
But it became burdensome whenever I tried to use different file for an input. I try implementing `JFileChooser` but with no luck.

This is the code, but nothing happening.

```
public static JFileChooser choose;
File directory = new File("B:\\");
choose = new JFileChooser(directory);
choose.setVisible(true);        
File openFile = choose.getSelectedFile();

FileReader fR = new FileReader(openFile);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fR);
```

Comment: for better help soon post SSCCE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per Java tutorial on [How to Use File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html):

> Bringing up a standard open dialog requires only two lines of code:

```
//Create a file chooser
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
...
//In response to a button click:
int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(aComponent);
```

> The argument to the showOpenDialog method specifies the parent
>   component for the dialog. The parent component affects the position of
>   the dialog and the frame that the dialog depends on.

Note [as per docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showOpenDialog%28java.awt.Component%29) it can also be:

```
int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
```

> If the parent is null, then the dialog depends on no visible window,
>   and it's placed in a look-and-feel-dependent position such as the
>   center of the screen.

Also have a read on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) if you haven't already.

Comment: I want it to run when my program starts without clicking anything from start.

Comment: @SndLt What the problem? simply use `fc.showOpenDialog(null);` as the parent can be `null`... See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showOpenDialog(java.awt.Component)) for more

Comment: Did it and added "FileReader fR = new FileReader(choose.getSelectedFile());" Thank you.

Comment: I've been trying to accept an answer, still have to wait 45 more seconds to accept.

Answer (score 2):

No blocking code (as David Kroukamp suggest). It solves "not showing up" problem.

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
    JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
    jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    if( jfc.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ){
        selected = jfc.getSelectedFile();
    }
}
}
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
```

Comment: Brilliant answer

Answer (score 1):

I personally found that the first dialog would show, but subsequent dialogs wouldn't show. I fixed it by reusing the same JFileChooser with this code.

```
JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
File jar = selectFile(jfc, "Select jar to append to");
File append = selectFile(jfc, "Select file to append");

//When done, remove the window
jfc.setVisible(false);

public static File selectFile(JFileChooser jfc, String msg) {
    if (!jfc.isVisible()) {
        jfc.setVisible(true);
        jfc.requestFocus();
    }

    int returncode = jfc.showDialog(null, msg);
    if (returncode == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) return jfc.getSelectedFile();
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `JFileChoosers`, you're supposed to call `objectName.showOpenDialog(Component parent)` or `objectName.showOpenDialog(Component parent)`. These methods will return an integer, which you can use to compare to the static constants set in JFileChooser to determine whether the user clicked cancel or open/save. You then use `getSelectedFile()` to retrieve the file that the user has selected.

Ex (There might be small errors):

```
class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
        File selected;

        if (jfc.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            selected = jfc.getSelectedFile();
        }
    }
}
```

The Java API is a great resource for figuring out what objects can do what, and how. Here's the page for [`JFileChoosers`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html)

The API pages are usually found when you Google the object name. They're usually the first ones that come up as a result as well.

Comment: It's a simple example. No need to get so complicated

Comment: [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) is not complicated simply wrapping code in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable r)` block will do the trick. As it stands IMO this is code with bad practice embedded

Comment: @AlexYan Do you have any idea of the number of problems we get here because of "examples".  It might be picky and pedantic, but if we can save our selves one more "example" question, then I'd be a happier developer :D

Comment: @MadProgrammer +1 spot on :). And I see the level of knowledge among posters in general does increase (I have seen a few more calling `super.paintComponent(g)`) Yay.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp No I don't know the amount of problems caused by small examples, nor do I know how to use EDT. I'm in high school, and we only touched on thread hacking, by ourselves...